# In rails, can you break up a single text_field into parts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, credit-card, textinput

I would like to take a credit card number, say :number and break it up into 4 text fields which update with JS to 3 text fields if the card put in is Amex.

I was thinking I could do

```
<%= fields_for :number do |c| %>
  <%= c.text_field 'cnumber1'>
  <%= c.text_field 'cnumber2'%>
  <%= c.text_field 'cnumber3'%>
  <%= c.text_field 'cnumber4'%> 
<% end %>
```

but that doesn't work.  I know I could set up html input tags and then change it up on the controller side, but for this particular situation I wanted to do it all in the view, because it's a transparent post to another server.

Now I'm just curious. It'd be cool to break up a date input too and separate all of a date object into separate text_fields as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could definitely do that:

- Create `attr_accessors` in your model
- add them to the form
- in a `before_save` callback, get the value from them the way you desire

Comment: definitely a good idea if I had access to the data when it's posted.  But it's going transparently to another server so I have to send it as the ojbects they're expecting right?

Comment: Well, if you don't use the data on your server, your form could be done using raw html or form_tag helpers, no need to think about Rails model here. Otherwise, You could keep attr_accessors and merge them with js on form submission.

Comment: In general, consider accepting some answers. It's simply fair.

Comment: But my question hasn't been answered.  I tried doing straight html and submitting the form via javascript but it had severe cross platform issues.  Maybe I should ask another question with regards to that

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to solve your problem by having four fields however, as far as dates are concerned, you can use the form.date_select helper and it will break your date into three fields (day, month, year).